# Translation for an autographed inscription

Tags: meaning, handwriting

[image: Autographed_Inscription_by_Albert_Speer]

Inscription in book by Albert Speer in Die Neue Reichskanzlei which may have been given to Admiral Erich Raeder

Answer (score 3):

> Herrn Großadmiral Raeder mit den herzlichsten Wünschen zugeeignet.
>
> Albert Speer, Berlin, den 25.IV.1940

Translates to

> Handed over (or dedicated) to Mr Grand Admiral Raeder with the most cordial wishes.
>
> Albert Speer, Berlin, 04/25/1940

*Zueignen* can mean both "to dedicate" or simply "give" or "hand over".

Comment: I still can't decipher "herzlichsten" after reading your translation, although it definitely makes sense. The "r" and "z" are unrecognizable to me. And I did not expect the spot of ink to actually be there on purpose.

Comment: Often it is a good idea not to try to decipher single letters but to look at the entire word's appearance (and position). Hand written stuff may have completely accidental or misplaced strokes (depending on the training of the writer; mine definitely has, not less than Speer's).

Comment: The spot is over the c, not the i, but otherwise it seams quite clear to me.